# git workflow for frequently exchanging commits between two branches

Tags: git, workflow, branch, commit

I have two (related) feature branches with frequent changes. Usually 1 or 2 out of 5 changes of each branch are also relevant for the other branch. Depending on the history I end up either cherry-picking, rebasing, or--if the branches converge again--merging.

This ends up in a quite messy view for external developers.

Although I studied similar SO questions, and believe to know when to rebase, when to merge etc., I cannot really figure out the intended git workflow for this particular scenario (or if this is normal).

Any pointers on what the git procedure is, or what I missed, are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider basing both feature branches off a main branch, and then putting the commits that aren't specific to a feature into the main branch and rebasing the feature branches onto the new main-branch commits.

(In other words, don't put commits on the feature branches unless they're actually associated with the feature in question. Make a third feature branch for developing separate commits if necessary, then merge that branch into the mainline when you're done.)

Comment: They are based off a main branch (sorry for not mentioning initially), but the decision ("oh wait, those subset of commits are required, but actually not specific to that feature only"), happens after the commits on review. A main branch in between does not simplify it, does it?

Comment: In that case, cherry-pick the now-shared commit to a shared branch, and rebase both feature branches on that.

Comment: I tried out your advice, and it creates a nicer flow :) Thx!